# I'm trying to convert a new Date() to the format of 2-13-2018

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datepicker

I have a value that shows as Sat Apr 28 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT) but I want to convert it to just 4/28/2018. and when I do value.toISOString(); it gives me back 2018-04-26T06:00:00.000Z, how do i take off the end part?

Comment: ...and? Have you tried _anything_?

Comment: whoops figured out it was a problem with my redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
var d = new Date(); // Your date object
console.log(dateString = getDateString(d));

function getDateString(date) {
    return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getYear();
    // Or
    return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getYear();
}
```

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate, you need `date.getMonth() + 1` and the year should use *getFullYear*.